# SSRS 2005 Report Viewer Date Picker Performance Issue

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, reportviewer

The date picker on the report viewer control in SSRS 2005 is causing our application to slow down a lot; when the user clicks the calendar icon, it really takes a while to load for them for some reason.  Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a query driving the default value? Maybe you need to investigate that. Put 'today' as a default and see if it changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the newer versions of Report Viewer ([2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=cc96c246-61e5-4d9e-bb5f-416d75a1b9ef&displaylang=en) or [2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a941c6b2-64dd-4d03-9ca7-4017a0d164fd) ) this control performed and may help you to solve your issue.

Note that, report viewer is totaly seperated from your reports and you can easily upgrade it.